# Dependency injection in the template class

Tags: design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design, templates

I have a template wrapper class around the container `std::priority_queue` that supports multithreading. The short version of it is below. In this class I employ the function `IsReady()` that checks whether the element is ready to be popped or not. Implementation of `IsReady()` depends on the type `T`.

At first I made `IsReady()` a class member of `PriorityQueue` and created a template specialized method for various types `T`. However, it seems as an incorrect idea to pollute this generic `PriorityQueue` class with such specializations.

```
#include <queue>
#include "pthread.h"

enum RV {
    SUCCESS = 0,
    ERROR = 1,
};

template <class T>
class PriorityQueue {

private:

    std::priority_queue<T> __priorityQueue;
    pthread_mutex_t __mutex;
    pthread_cond_t __condition;

public:

    PriorityQueue();
    void Push(T element);
    RV TryPop(T * element);

};

template <class T>
PriorityQueue<T>::PriorityQueue() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&__mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&__condition, NULL);
}

template <class T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::Push(T element) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&__mutex);
    __priorityQueue.push(element);
    pthread_cond_signal(&__condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&__mutex);
}

template <class T>
RV PriorityQueue<T>::TryPop(T * element) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&__mutex);
    if (__priorityQueue.empty()) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&__mutex);
        return ERROR;
    }
    *element = __priorityQueue.top();
    if (!IsReady(*element)) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&__mutex);
        return ERROR;
    }
    __priorityQueue.pop();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&__mutex);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Questions:**

1) Is it fine in general to have something like `IsReady()` methods in such generic classes as `PriorityQueue`?

2) What is the best option to inject `IsReady()` method into this class (template specialization, passing function pointer to the constructor of `PriorityQueue` etc)?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What - in detail - is `IsReady` supposed to check, and can you avoid the need for `IsReady` by providing a generic `Top` function?

Comment: @Doc Brown For example, type `T` may be an object that represents a timer and `IsReady()` checks that the timer is ready to be invoked. In this case, `IsReady()` compares current system time and time in timer object.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it fine?"  Without knowing what "fine" means to you specifically (other than some random internet person's judgement of "acceptable"), that question is unanswerable.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why you need a method `IsReady` for which calls are bound to the mutex of the priority queue.

Comment: IsReady() creates a race condition. Make sure the operations you wish to perform can be completed using only one call.